# PHImageManager.requestImageForAsset for HighQualityFormat never calls resultHandler

Tags: ios, phasset, photosframework

I have a Collection View that presents a list of photo library images, and on selection, I want to fetch the highest quality version and present a controller to crop it.

My Collection View's call(s) work properly:.

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.networkAccessAllowed = true

PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 480, height: 640), contentMode:.AspectFit, options:options, resultHandler:{(image, info)in

    print("PhotosVC RECEIVED image size \(image!.size.width) x \(image!.size.height)")

    cell.ImageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    cell.ImageView?.image = image
})
```

The resultHandler is called one or more times - usually two, the first returning 60x45, and then again later at 480x360.

After a cell is selected, a different ViewController calls requestImageForAsset with the HighQualityFormat option:

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.networkAccessAllowed = true
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat

let ret = PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 768, height: 1024), contentMode:.AspectFit, options:options, resultHandler:{(image, info)in

    print("RootVC RECEIVED image size \(image!.size.width) x \(image!.size.height)")
    // stuff here - never called
})
```

The resultHandler is never called when I run this code on my device (iPad Mini Retina, iOS 9.3.2).  **It does get called on the Simulator, 100% of the time.  Seems to be a device-only bug, or a bug specific to certain photos (100% reproducible on the device)**

I've tried a lot of different variations on this call; if I remove the deliveryMode = HighQualityFormat constraint, the resultHandler is called successfully, multiple times, at lower resolutions.

Would welcome any ideas or insight.

Comment: Try doing this on a background thread with `synchronous` set to `true`. — Also, be sure you're waiting long enough; if this is an image being fetched over the network, maybe it really takes a while?

Comment: Tried putting it inside  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) { ... }; still seeing the same behavior unfortunately, which is that the code in the resultHandler block is never executed, even if I wait several minutes.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this may be a problem with my iPad - the Photos app is having problems loading old images in higher resolution, and screenshots I'm taking aren't making their way to the Camera Roll.  Going to investigate this angle.

Comment: That was it - the symptoms were that new photos and screenshots were not appearing in the Photos app / Camera roll, and also the behavior described in the question.  A hard reset of the device (home+lock for 15+ sec) solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that my test device was in a bad state.

The primary symptom was that new photos and screenshots taken with Apple's apps were not appearing in the Camera Roll or anywhere in the Photos app.

A hard reset on the device (home+lock for 15 sec) solved the above symptoms, and now the resultHandler is called for HighQualityFormat in the expected manner.

Comment: Nice work. You probably know that you can accept your own answer in 48 hours, and you should do so.

Comment: I can't up vote this enough. I spent hours trying to fix my working code that suddenly wouldn't accept any solution. This was the case for me too, thanks for posting this answer